# Laravel Broadcasting: Notification vs Event

Tags: php, laravel

I read Laravel documentations about `Events` and `Notifications`, it seems we can fire an event and from that event (using `ShouldBroadcast` interface) broadcast it to Laravel echo which i understand, in the other hand we can use Notifications `viaBroadcast` to do the same, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After thinking a lot, i found out that they are made for different things, here's what i understood:

**Notifications:**

Consider facebook, everytime you login you see bunch of notifications about things that happened while you where away, also if you are present you see live notifications..

meanwhile you're getting emails about notifications that you want..
this is exactly what Laravel Notifications is doing.
you can use `notify` method on your eloquent models such as `App\User` about something like `OrderApproved` which will do whatever you planned it to do for you like sending sms to that user. and also you can save one instant of that notification on database so when user comes back he or she can see that you have approved their order..

**Events:**

it's when something happens, like when a new user is created and you want to do different things like sending verification email, sending verification sms and.. this is why you create an event so that you could handle different logics of that event using listeners.
when it comes to broadcasting, you can use `ShouldBroadcast` interface on your event and from there you can sync data with your admin panel that a new user is registered. this will be useful when admin is watching list of users and without reloading the page you could user `Laravel Echo` to receive that event on admin panel and append new registered user to the list.

**Conclusion:**

it really depends on what you need, if you just want to update something in your interface, maybe events are what you need. but if you need to do more you can use notifications.

in the end events are used when you need to do things when something happens while notifications are report of what just happened.

hope it help others..

Comment: actually you can make your own notification mechanism with event-listener, but Laravel provide out of the box solution to track your activity, especially if you use database notification because you do not need to know how laravel filter the notification data, laravel provide all things for you. Even slack, nexmo, mail, broadcast you can triggered from event manually, but notification wrap all of this to make more easy to implement.

Comment: "but if you need to do more you can use notifications" sounds strange, like events and notifications are different approaches to do the same (or more), but they're different things. In fact, I think notifications should be called inside event listeners, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: "but if you need to do more you can use notifications"
This seems wrong, if you have a good reason and example for this, please explain

Answer (score 109):

What the provided answer lacks imo is that they are in most cases used both instead of 1 or the other, which seems to be the tone of the provided answer/question.

An event is something significant in your application. Let's assume your application is a Webshop.

A significant action in your webshop can be *Product Purchased* . When a product is purchased you need to do a lot of different steps. Putting this all inside a controller and potentially in several different places can get very messy and not clear.

So a good approach would be to use a **Event** called **ProductPurchased** . This event can have Listeners, those listeners are in this case all the steps you need to perform when a user purchases a product.

e.g.:
ProductPurchased (event)

- BillClient  (eventlistener)
- GenerateInvoice (eventlistener)
- notifyClient (eventlistener)
- ...

Let's say we want to notify our client with a text-message and an email when they purchased a product.

So on the notifyClient event-listener we can create a **Notification** . This notification is responsible for sending a message to the client. This can be a SMS/Slack-message/Email/...

And like you mentioned both Events and Notifications can be put on the Queue or can be broadcasted. Broadcasting is mainly used in combination with Laravel Echo and the use of Websockets.

You choose notifications when you want to send something to **different channels**. Mail/SMS/Slack..
If you only need broadcasting you can just use ShouldBroadcast. Just like when you only want to send an e-mail use Mail:: without the need for a notification.

Notifications are a nice way to group the same 'message' to different destinations.

Comment: Excellent indepth answer that should have been up-voted a lot more!

Comment: I think what the original question refers to is instead of doing `event(new ProductPurchased)` and the 3 listeners firing, why not use the `broadcastOn` method in ProductPurchased and not have the notifyClient listener.

Comment: Sure, but the question says that he understands broadcasting. Which is websocket stuff, which is mostly used to show users real-time information inside your application. While notifications are used to send to users. Listeners are just classes that should be triggered after a important action. Its not eventlisteners or notifications or broadcasting , they kan be done all for a certain action. They serve a different purpose.

Comment: you know, I signed up for a stackoverflow account today using my gmail, simply to upvote this answer... I came here to determine why to use either or, and I couldn't grasp my head around the difference... This answer is concise and proper... You utilize an Event to state "Something Important Happened" and then you utilize listeners to trigger those things happened... I personally, don't think broadcasting should be a part of the Event System anymore now that Notifications are enabled, because a broadcast to me seems like it should be a listener concern anyways! THANKS SO MUCH @Christophvh

Comment: @RomanLopez  Thanks for the kind words! Broadcasting is still useful when using web sockets. Broadcasting is the solution when using laravel Echo for building a chat app for example.

Comment: Digging this up slightly but require some further information relating to the notifications. From looking at documentation would I be right to assume that Laravel recommend on creating a new 'notification' class for each type of notification. In the case of an invoice, CreateInvoiceNotification, EditInvoiceNotification & DeleteInvoiceNotification? Seems like a lot of duplicated code?

Comment: @CreativeNerdSam Laravel does not really recommend anything. If they do almost the same, just make a if() in a single class. If they do different things make seperate notifications. It is your code, so you would know the best solution for your project.

Comment: This goes part way to explaining stuff, but this doesn't explain why it's possible to broadcast from a notification when you could just do it from an event implementing `shouldBroadcast`

I mean, why... event => listener => notification => broadcast, when you can just do event => broadcast....

Comment: @ortonomy You are correct, broadcast & notifications are 2 seperate things. You juse notifications when you want to send to multiple sources. Slack/Mail/Mobile notifications & maybe broadcasting. If you only need broadcasting you don't need notifications like you said. Just like you can send a mail without the need for notifications.

Comment: @Christophvh -- ummm, I didn't make a distinction between broadcasting and notifications, or care about that here. I'm saying that broadcasting can be achieved from notifications AND events. So what is the functional difference, if any, between notifications and events. Otherwise, it seems pointless to have notifications. The laravel documentation even suggests sending a slack notification from an event listener 

Comment: @ortonomy Notifications are very focused. Let's say you want to send a customer 'product purchased' via Mail/Slack/SMS/Facebook messenger/..  .Notification should be your choice because it has helpers(like auto-translation or the notifiable model) to achieve this and has clean and helpful methods to activate/deactive notifcation-channels. I always trigger notifications inside event-listeners if i need multiple channels otherwise I just do it in the listener.

Comment: So is correct to assume that when you need to send "something" through more than 1 via (WebSockets/email/FCM/Pushkit) a good approach is to dispatch a notification? Should I dispatch the notification directly within the controller if there is nothing to do that may involve an Event

Comment: @Luciano yes correct. Notifications do not require an event or listener. In your case, only a notification is perfectly fine.