# When to use events in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, listener

I am new to laravel, and I have a question about the usage of events.

As far as I understand, events are used when some actions such as registering users occur and handle logic following those actions such as sending a confirmation email.

But what I do not understand is that why can't I just create a helper function which would handle those actions instead of creating event and listener files.

In other words, what is the advantages of using events?

Thank you.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314809/laravel-boardcasting-notification-vs-event

Answer (score 5):

Using `events` and `listeners` just another approach to implement that use observer pattern. Of course it has its own advantages. As the laravel document said:

> Events serve as a great way to decouple various aspects of your
>   application, since a single event can have multiple listeners that do
>   not depend on each other. For example, you may wish to send a Slack
>   notification to your user each time an order has shipped. Instead of
>   coupling your order processing code to your Slack notification code,
>   you can simply raise an OrderShipped event, which a listener can
>   receive and transform into a Slack notification.

Answer (score 2):

Using `events` and `listeners` instead of helpers can have 2 additional benefits:

1. [Stopping The Propagation Of An Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-listeners) (without extra conditionals)
2. [Queuing the implementation login](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#queued-event-listeners)

   -> Mails, external calls, etc. take time. We can let the server do it later by using queues leading to the better User experience.

Comment: I think #2 is a reason to use a Job rather than an event.